# onclick lightning button key-field value return undefined in js

Tags: lightning-web-components

Actually i have following template:

```
<template for:each={Orders.data} for:item="ord">
  <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={ord.Id}>
    <td>
      <div class="slds-truncate" key={ord.Id}>{ord.SalesDocument}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="slds-truncate" key={ord.Id}>{ord.NetAmount}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="slds-truncate" key={ord.Id}>{ord.OrderDate}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="slds-truncate" key={ord.Id}>{ord.OrderStatus}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="slds-truncate" key={ord.Id}><lightning-button icon-name="utility:print" variant="border-filled" title="Print" key-field = "SalesDocument" onclick={handlePdfAction} alternative-text="Print"></lightning-button></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

and following function in js:

```
handlePdfAction(event) {
  const row = event.detail.row;
  console.log('handlerowaction '+row);
}
```

when i click on button i got undefined value.please i am new to lwc.Thanks.

Comment: It has been resolved.Thanks

Comment: You should add the resolution as an answer so that this question stands resolved.

Comment: I added data-key attribute to button and pass value in js as: handlePdfAction(event) { console.log(event.currentTarget.dataset.key);